# Setup.py for Utility Python project

Tags: python, setuptools

Should/does a utility Python project need a `setup.py` file? My utility project will train a computer vision model with sample images. It depends on a computer vision python module/package. It will be used internally and not publicly distributed.

Is a setup.py file useful or applicable for this kind of Python project?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is certainly useful to setup packaging even for internal libraries.  You'll want to write a `setup.py` if you'd like any of the benefits below:

- Users to be able to install your stuff with `pip install myutility`
- Different versions, e.g. one user on `myutility==1.0.1` and another on `myutility==1.2.1`
- Control / management of dependencies (see [`install_requires`](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies))
- To use continuous integration and software dev best practices (e.g. the tests must have passed for code to be released)

The only time I would consider omitting `setup.py` is for quick throwaway scripts that have no external dependencies.